# Django: Когда стоит создавать отдельно приложение, а когда писать в одном?

Tags: python, django, архитектура, проектирование

Пишу что-то типа CRM для небольшой производственной компании на Django. С расчетами, статистикой и пользователями. Django изучаю недавно и можно сказать, что это первые шаги на практике. Немного не понимаю, когда нужно создавать отдельное приложение? Или нормально, когда весь проект и все возможности прописаны внутри одного приложения (не проекта, а именно app)?
Кажется, что приложение в django проекте - программа решающая определенную и конкретную задачу. 
Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: Это вопрос только здравого смысла и удобства. На вроде вопроса "Во сколько пакетов разложить покупки?" Одно точно - если какой-то функционал полностью самостоятелен и его можно применить в другом проекте, однозначно стоить завернуть его в отдельный app.

Answer (score 3):

**Отдельное приложение создается когда:**

1. требуется логически разделить функционал
2. необходимо применить на нескольких сайтах сразу
3. распространяем приложение для других
4. приложение слишком разрастается, работать не удобно.

Приложения в django **являются пакетом в python**. Они могут находиться в общих пакетах системы, виртуальном окружении, папке проекта.

**Возможна перезапись одного пакета другим.**
Данную особенность необходимо всегда учитывать, назовем свое приложение sys или json или другим именем из стандартной библиотеки и получим проблемы которые не всегда сразу видны. 
Но при этом если хотим зафиксировать версию django или пакета, можно не создавать виртуальное окружение, а все скопировать рядом папку проекта.